# How to design prototype UITableViewCell in Xamarin Designer?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, uistoryboard, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to create a storyboard for my iOS project in the Xamarin Studio Designer.
I drag a `UITableViewController` into the scene and set the number of *dynamic prototype cells to 1*.
Now I'm trying to drag a `UILabel` (or a button or whatever) into the prototype cell. The UI indicates that the insertion can be done and alignment helpers appear. However the label never gets added. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? The screenshot shows the label being dragged, but it cannot be dropped.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First You have to drag a cell then after drag label on that cell.

Comment: This is not the correct way to answer a question,Read all the FAQ portions and do use some steps like list to tell your approach,and give some explanations about that.